# Scrypto: Decimal type to any usize

Tags: radix, scrypto

## How do I convert from Decimal type to usize of any type in Scrypto

```
let my_decimal= dec!("7");
let my_uint = 12;
let my_remainder = my_uint % my_decimal;
```

expected to get my_remainder = 5

But I got cannot calculate the remainder of `{integer}` divided by `scrypto::prelude::Decimal` the trait `Rem<scrypto::prelude::Decimal>` is not implemented for `{integer}` the following other types implement trait `Rem<Rhs>`: